# codeigniter performance controller CI_Controller

Tags: php, performance, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter only for api.

I analyzed access logs on server 
on average get call taking approx 5 seconds 
and post calls also taking on average 5 seconds.

in system\core\Controller.php there is class named CI_Controller
and in following line inside constructor taking 4 seconds.

this problem only coming after I moved all my codeigniter code in new server,
in older server on average it was taking less than 1 seconds.

I am trying to solve this issue.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: CI is one of the fastest frameworks out there - so nobody can tell what you are doing within your functions - maybe u r using sessions in combination with ajax calls maybe not - nevertheless you've to provide a lot more information than that...

Comment: There is no problem with CI_Controller of system\core\Controller.php. Each controller of codeigniter extends this class CI_Controller so this class will be called in each controller which may show that its taking time. but indirectly it is calling by your controller which is taking time.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter controllers looks like:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Customname extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Which means your `Customname` controller is extending core framework class `system\core\Controller.php` named CI_Controller and it will call  `parent::__construct();` which is nothing but construct of core CI_Controller.

So your custom code or functionalities is effecting it. There may be several reasons:

- Check autoload libraries and helpers.
- check if any hook is being called before controller function.
- check if problem exists with session Etc.